# Fill Cells in range in single Column, but Only the next blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot seem to find what i am looking for so here i am.

The situation: We have a spreadsheet that is used by multiple users. They will have to fill in certain cells with an employee's name, but they must be typed exactly as in our system. To remove as much human error as possible, we are making a simple button they can push after typing in their last name and a Vlookup gives us the proper format.

Problem: There are about 10 cells all in one column (B10:B19) that are where the names will go. The vlookup output is in Cell G4. So we want if they press the button, the contents of G4 goes in the next available cell within that range of B10-B19. I have gotten close but it appears to skip some lines and miss others.

Here is what i have so far:

```
Sub SecondTestFunction()

    Dim cellRange As Range
    Dim nameInCell As Range
    Set cellRange = Range("B11:B20")
    
        'Loop through cells in range B11 thru B20
    For i = 1 To cellRange.Count
    
        'Set nameInCell to equal the index of column B
        Set nameInCell = cellRange(i)
        
        'If the cell in Column B is empty....
        If IsEmpty(nameInCell) Then
            'Paste the name from cell G4...
            nameInCell(i).Value = Range("G4")
                GoTo GoToHere
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell is NOT EMPTY"
            nameInCell(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Testing line to see which get affected
        
        End If

    Next i

GoToHere:

MsgBox "Done looping"

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `nameInCell.Value = Range("G4")`? I think you could avoid a loop using specialcells.

Comment: Why not just have a drop-down with all names or some simple filter to the drop-down menu. Say type first letter and it gives you a list of names starting with that letter? Or grab the name from windows ( the person logged in) if that is a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Sub SecondTest()

    Dim c As Range, bFound As Boolean, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always use an explicit sheet
   
    For Each c in ws.Range("B11:B20").Cells
        If Len(c.value) = 0 Then
            c.Value = ws.Range("G4").Value
            bFound = True
            Exit for
        End If
    Next c
    
    If not bFound Then Msgbox "No empty cell found!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a gem. Thank you for the answer.